# Excel:Set the maximum number of rows to display in a combo box on a form

Tags: excel, combobox, vba

I want to delete vertical scroll bar in combo box Level2.

I tried to change List Rows in property box but it didn't work.

[image]

Comment: `ListRows` property can take a value from 1-255. See this link: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff822058.aspx. What did you enter?

Answer (score 0):

The ListRows property ***is*** the one that you want. You can't make the scroll bar go away if the number of items in the list is greater than the ListRows property. If you really don't want to see it, set the ListRows property to a much larger value. Beware that anything that drops off the edge of the screen will be unreadable though.

Comment: I have two combo box in my file and if i set the ListRows property to a much larger value for first combo box it work for it, but not for second combo box. For example: for first I set 15 and it's 15, but for second it's still just 5 and not 15 right after scroling list down. May be there are other ways to solve this problem?

Comment: You have to set the property on each Combo Box. Each box is a different object, thus when you change box 1 properties, box 2 properties are not affected.